# Redefining a Iframe URL via php code

Tags: php, html

I want to set the url of an iframe using PHP, my url is in that format : http://mysite.com/s/ where  = numbers, I want to make a button that increase the number in the url of 1 and reload the iframe.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <form class="topBorder">
            <p>
                <?php
                    $site = 6394100;

                    function NextSite($sites)
                    {
                        $sites += 1;
                        return 'http://mywebsite.com/s/' . $sites . '/';
                    }

                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo NextSite($sites); ?>" target="frame"> Next </a>
            </p>
            <iframe name="frame" id="frame" src="http://mywebsite.com/s/" class="gagFrame"></iframe>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can take help of a simple JS function for this. See the modified code below. I have not tested it but you should get the idea of doing it.

EDIT:

You need to get it done the ajax way. Put your php function in a file say loadurl.php:

```
            <?php
                $site = 6394100;

                   $sites += 1;
                   echo 'http://mywebsite.com/s/' . $sites . '/';
            ?>
```

Now in your html code do as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <form class="topBorder">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadURL()
    { 
         $.get('pathToloadurl.php',success(data)
         {
             window.frames[siteFrame].location =data;
         });
     }
    </script>
   <button type="button" onClick="loadURL()">Next</button>
   <iframe name="siteFrame" id="frame" src="http://mywebsite.com/s/" class="gagFrame"></iframe>
 </form>
```

Comment: see my edit to fetch URL with ajax. You wil need to include JQUERY for this to work.

Comment: How do I include jquery ? I've no idea of what it is

Comment: include this in head tag: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>. I recommend to you to learn jquery as its a indispensable tool for any web developer.

Comment: check browser console for errors. Also check the path you have given to get request in the loadURL function. The path should be towards your loadurl.php file that you have created.

Comment: I'll do it ! But, can you refer me a link ? An easy tutorial plz :)